# Cython vs numpy performance scaling

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I've been playing around with Cython in preparation for other work. I tried a simple test case and noticed something odd with the way my code performs for larger problem sizes. I created a simple min/max function that calculates the min and max of a 2D float32 array and compared it to running `numpy.min(a), numpy.max(a)`. For an array of 10000 elements the performance was similar. For an array of 1000000 elements the cython performed much worse. Here's my cython code:

```
import numpy
cimport cython
cimport numpy

DTYPE = numpy.float32
ctypedef numpy.float32_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def minmax_float32(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] arr):
    cdef DTYPE_t min = arr[0, 0]
    cdef DTYPE_t max = arr[0, 0]
    cdef int row_max = arr.shape[0]
    cdef int col_max = arr.shape[1]
    cdef int x, y
    for y in range(row_max):
        for x in range(col_max):
            if arr[y, x] < min:
                min = arr[y, x]
            if arr[y, x] > max:
                max = arr[y, x]

    return min, max
```

And here's my simple timing done in ipython:

```
a = numpy.random.random(10000).reshape((100, 100)).astype(numpy.float32)
%timeit -r3 -n50 (numpy.min(a), numpy.max(a))
# 50 loops, best of 3: 22.2 µs per loop

%timeit -r3 -n50 minmax_float32(a)
# 50 loops, best of 3: 23.8 µs per loop

a = numpy.random.random(1000000).reshape((1000, 1000)).astype(numpy.float32)
%timeit -r3 -n50 (numpy.min(a), numpy.max(a))
# 50 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop

%timeit -r3 -n50 minmax_float32(a)
# 50 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop

307 / 22.2
# 13.82882882882883

1220 / 23.8
# 51.26050420168067
```

Does anyone have ideas for why cython takes so much longer for the larger input? And this was just something I was playing with, but if you have any tips or tricks I'm interested in hearing them. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I ran these tests on a macbook 10.10 with 8GB of memory. Compiled the cython with gcc from macports with the flags mentioned in their tutorials `-shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: What happens if you flip your inner and outer loops?

Comment: Good question, it goes up to ~7ms. All I did was switch the two `for` lines.

Comment: I'm guessing that the compiler is struggling to properly autovectorize   - see [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/LfBH6M7gNTc/B19uFB5YbYYJ).

Comment: @daveydave400 That's to be expected because of data locality. By default `numpy` stores arrays in row-major order, so you should hope that having your inner loop run over a row will be faster, and it is.

Comment: I think @dan-man is right. It's also quite possible that `numpy` is calling whatever BLAS you have installed, like the Intel MKL, which may be multithreaded and optimized for your specific hardware. So it may not be a case of you doing something *wrong*, it could be a case of `numpy` doing something very right.

Comment: The difference will likely not be much, but the second `if` in your Cython code should be an `elif`.

Comment: I think you're all right. I tried switching to `elif` @Jaime, I tried doing `-O3`, and I skimmed for any SSE4 instructions that might help this (without trying too hard) and while the binary changed size it was not a noticeable difference in execution time. I don't know if I care enough to look at the actual assembly/binary instructions being run. @dan-man or @jme if you want to make an answer I'll accept it if you're hungry for reputation.

Comment: @daveydave400: just tried your code in my environment, and the results are completely different: your implementation is always a bit faster, does not depend on the size much. So it depends.

Comment: @RomanL I suppose that can be expected. I ran this code on a linux server I have access to and got similar results. Actually worse, almost the same for 10000 elements, but for one million its ~910us for numpy and ~3.2ms on cython. Edit: I should note that I ran this with anaconda on the linux machine.

Comment: @daveydave400: just out of curiosity, what would be results on your machine for native C/C++ code? E.g. http://pastebin.com/u9xV5U53 with `g++ -O2 test.cpp && ./a.out`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like NumPy uses SSE instructions where available for `min` and `max`, which means they can likely take advantage of your hardware to a much greater extent than Cython can achieve.

Here's the source code for NumPy's `min` and `max` reduction implementations in SSE: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src#L696. Note that they are using a preprocessor to automatically generate code for multiple datatypes and operations simultaneously.

Comment: I had looked through the numpy source, but ended up finding `loops.c.src` which doesn't have any optimizations. This definitely looks like it could make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

First to avoid confusion it is never a good idea to use the build in function names min and max as variable names so call the fmin and fmax.

Basically it is worth remembering that numpy is highly optimised, you might also try in your cython changing:

```
    for x in range(col_max):
        if arr[y, x] < min:
            min = arr[y, x]
        if arr[y, x] > max:
            max = arr[y, x]
```

to:

```
    for x in range(col_max):
        val = arr[y, x]
        if val < fmin:
            fmin = val
        if val > fmax:
            fmax = val
```

and adding the definition: `cdef DTYPE_t val`

This will reduce the number of array index operations from 4 to 1.

You could also try using:

```
    (fmin, fmax) = (min(fmin, val), max(fmax, val))
```

as it may show some improvement.

You can also make x, y, row_max and row_min into **unsigned** ints and turn off bounds checking by adding the function decorator `@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function`

This [tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) is worth reading.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but nothing happened with the execution time. I already had the bounds checking turned off and had looked at that tutorial (although it seems like it was copied to their user guide which is what I followed). I did not do the `cdef DTYPE_t max` because I'm not really sure what you meant by that. What would that do?

Comment: Sorry the typedef was supposed to be of val. Edited above. This would prevent the creation of a new val time after time.